# Logrotate add suffix to a rotated log file: Nested

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

on a Debian host is running a rsyslog server , which takes logs from the firewall.
Everything works fine except for my logrotate configuration which adds another suffix to a rotated log and that makes the whole thing messy.

logrotate-nested suffix:

> /var/log/rsyslog/

```
    log_server.x.log_2023-01-31.gz_2023-02-02.gz_2023-02-04.gz_2023-02-06.gz_2023-02-08.gz_2023-02-10.gz_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16.gz_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-01.gz_2023-02-03.gz_2023-02-05.gz_2023-02-07.gz_2023-02-09.gz_2023-02-11.gz_2023-02-13.gz_2023-02-15.gz_2023-02-17.gz_2023-02-19.gz_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-02.gz_2023-02-04.gz_2023-02-06.gz_2023-02-08.gz_2023-02-10.gz_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16.gz_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-03.gz_2023-02-05.gz_2023-02-07.gz_2023-02-09.gz_2023-02-11.gz_2023-02-13.gz_2023-02-15.gz_2023-02-17.gz_2023-02-19.gz_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-04.gz_2023-02-06.gz_2023-02-08.gz_2023-02-10.gz_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16.gz_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-05.gz_2023-02-07.gz_2023-02-09.gz_2023-02-11.gz_2023-02-13.gz_2023-02-15.gz_2023-02-17.gz_2023-02-19.gz_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-06.gz_2023-02-08.gz_2023-02-10.gz_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16.gz_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-11.gz_2023-02-13_2023-02-15_2023-02-17_2023-02-19_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14_2023-02-16_2023-02-18_2023-02-20
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-12.gz_2023-02-14_2023-02-16_2023-02-18_2023-02-20_2023-02-22.gz_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-13.gz_2023-02-15_2023-02-17_2023-02-19_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16_2023-02-18_2023-02-20
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-14.gz_2023-02-16_2023-02-18_2023-02-20_2023-02-22.gz_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-18.gz_2023-02-20_2023-02-22.gz_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-19.gz_2023-02-21_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-20.gz_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-21.gz_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-22
    log_server.x.log_2023-02-22.gz_2023-02-22_2023-02-22
```

my configuration:

```
 /var/log/rsyslog/* {
        rotate 30
        daily
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y%m%d
        create 0644 root root
        compress
        delaycompress
        postrotate
               /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
        endscript

}
```

Comment: You didn't really ask a question, but rather just wrote down your problem - without explaining *anything*. Please check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask better questions. Putting in more effort when asking questions can lead to better answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After changing /var/log/rsyslog/* this setting, i do get now a clear logrotate files.